# Метка карты яндекс

Tags: javascript

Как вывести координаты метки при нажатии на кнопку "ссылочка"? :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>»&#470075;&#39025;&#658482;. &#1120;&#35685;&#416616;&#22632;&#60645;&#133810;&#39149;&#64096;&#47216;&#768045;&#2161;&#722989;&#40421;</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    [JS]<script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ymaps.ready(init);
        var myMap, 
            myPlacemark,prev;

        function init(){ 
            myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
                center: [55.76, 37.64],
                zoom: 7
            }); 

            myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.76, 37.64], {
                hintContent: 'Москва',
                balloonContent: 'БЛАБЛА'
            });
          myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);



        }

    </script>[/JS]
</head>

<body>

    <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
    <a onclick="toggle(hidden_content)">Ссылочка</a>



<div id="hidden_content" style="display: none;">[JS]<script>
document.write();
</script>[/JS]</div>

[JS]<script>

function toggle(el) {

el.style.display = (el.style.display == 'none') ? '' : 'none'

}

</script>[/JS]




</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    ymaps.ready(init);

var myMap,
    myPlacemark;

function init(){ 
        myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
            center: [55.76, 37.64],
            zoom: 7
        });

        myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.76, 37.64], {
            hintContent: 'Москва',
            balloonContent: 'БЛАБЛА'
        });

      myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);

    }

 function toggle(el) {
    var coordinates = myPlacemark.geometry.getCoordinates();

    el.innerHTML = coordinates;
    el.style.display = (el.style.display == 'none') ? '' : 'none'

}
```